# Can't get mongojs (node-mongodb-native wrapper) to work on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I used `npm install mongojs` to get the wrapper, but when trying to run 
my app I get the following error:

```
node.js:195 
     throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick 
           ^
Native bson parser not compiled, please compile or avoid using  native_parser=true
```

I then tried to get the source from github and compile node-mongodb- 
native myself. Then I get the following error when running make:

```
make -C ./external-libs/bson  
make[1]: Entering directory`/tmp/node-mongodb-native/external-libs/bson`
rm -rf build.lock-wscript bson.node  node-waf configure build  
Checking for program g++ or c++: /usr/bin/g++  
Checking for program cpp: /usr/bin/cpp  
Checking for program ar: /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib: /usr/bin/ranlib  
Checking for g++: ok  
Checking for node path: not found  
Checking for node prefix: ok 
/usr/local 'configure' finished successfully (0.069s)  

Waf: Entering directory `/tmp/node-mongodb-native/external-libs/bson/build'  
[1/9] cxx: bson.cc -> build/default/bson_1.o  
[2/9] cxx: long.cc -> build/default/long_1.o  
[3/9] cxx: objectid.cc -> build/default/objectid_1.o  
[4/9] cxx: binary.cc -> build/default/binary_1.o      
[5/9] cxx: code.cc -> build/default/code_1.o  
[6/9] cxx: dbref.cc -> build/default/dbref_1.o  
../bson.cc:7:25: fatal error: node_events.h: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated. 
../objectid.cc:6:25: fatal error: node_events.h: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated.  
../code.cc:6:25: fatal error: node_events.h: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated. 
../dbref.cc:6:25: fatal error: node_events.h: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated.  
../long.cc:6:25: fatal error: node_events.h: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated. 
../binary.cc:7:25: fatal error: node_events.h: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated.  
Waf: Leaving directory `/tmp/node-mongodb-native/external-libs/bson/build'  
Build failed: -> task failed (err #1): 
     {task: cxx objectid.cc -> objectid_1.o}   -> task failed (err#1): 
     {task: cxx bson.cc -> bson_1.o}   -> task failed (err #1): 
     {task: cxx code.cc -> code_1.o}   -> task failed (err #1): 
     {task: cxx dbref.cc -> dbref_1.o}   -> task failed (err #1): 
     {task: cxx long.cc -> long_1.o}   -> task failed (err #1): 
     {task: cxx binary.cc -> binary_1.o}  make[1]: *** [all] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/node-mongodb-native/external-libs/bson'  
make: *** [build_native] Error 2
```

Any ideas to why this is failing and how I can make it work?

Answer (score 1):

before things are fixed you must use node 0.5.1 (you can use gitk to revert the tree to this version)

```
Auteur: Ryan Dahl <ry@tinyclouds.org>  2011-07-19 10:46:38
Auteur du commit: Ryan Dahl <ry@tinyclouds.org>  2011-07-19 10:46:38
Parent: 0a3fc1d9c8becc32c63ae736ca2b3719a3d03c5b (Remove StatWatcher's dep on C++ EventEmitter)
Enfant:  061ce7b0ac370c8a5ae93d95ab7da171cbd488f0 (net_uv: Fix simple/test-http-expect-continue.js)
Branche: master, remotes/origin/master
Suit: v0.5.1
Précède: v0.5.2
Finally remove node::EventEmitter
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add Node to your PATH in .bashrc or whatever the file is, depending on your distro.

See this link: http://shapeshed.com/journal/setting-up-nodejs-and-npm-on-mac-osx/

Answer (score 0):

The No such file or directory compilation terminated error could mean that you have not created a data/db directory for MongoDB to use.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
$ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

I seem to remember seeing something like this when I tried connecting to the MongoDB using the shell. Can you connect using the shell???

Answer (score 0):

Softwarepadawan, Please upgrade to the latest version of Mongjs. This afternoon I pushed a commit that fixes this and uses the JS parser instead of native parser.

Comment: The diff - https://github.com/gett/mongojs/commit/3c052020c9aff66d03d7c82a8decb7a0299b1385